# How can I use a Laravel closure to call a controller's __invoke() method?

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I have created a controller named InvokableController. It contains this function:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

I'd like to be able to call the __invoke method, like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $invokableObj = new InvokableController();
    $invokableObj();
})->name('home');
```

While this works:

```
Route::get('/', 'InvokableController')->name('home');
```

It's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to call the invoke method in this manner:

```
$invokableObj = new InvokableController();
$invokableObj();
```

I tried with and without the parentheses after `InvokableController`, on the line that assigns `$invokableObj`, with no luck.

I don't get any error messages. I tried returning something else at the bottom of the closure, like the number 1, and it renders 1 in the browser, so I know we're getting through the previous lines of code.

`APP_DEBUG` is `true`. Other error messages are rendered where I mess up. Does that make this some type of logical error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just a class, so `$invokableObj->__invoke()` should work just fine. Or you can use laravel DI:

```
app()->call(InvokableController::class . '@__invoke');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return app()->call(InvokableController::class . '@__invoke'); 
    // or
    $invokableObj = new InvokableController();
    return $invokableObj->__invoke();
})->name('home');
```

Comment: Thank you, Tymur. Unfortunately, `$invokableObj->__invoke()` does not render the view either, and it still doesn't provide me with an error message. I'll try the DI and get back to you.

Comment: You should return it from callback function in your route.

Comment: DI isn't working either. The only way that seems to work is not using a closure at all, like `Route::get('/', 'InvokableController')`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it.

Comment: Returning it from the callback function did the trick! I guess you can't return a view from a controller without also returning the return within the closure.

Comment: I just verified that all three options in your revised answer work as expected. Thank you!